# Во-2-х / во 2-х

Tags: орфография, вводные-слова, числительные, раздельно-дефис, сокращения

Как верно?

> В-одна-тысяча-сто-тридцать-восьмых, я хочу сказать, что это всё.
> В-1138-х / в 1138-х, я хочу сказать, что это всё.

А здесь?

> Во-вторых, я устал.
> Во-2-х / во 2-х, я устал.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

• Посмотрим, что о [**сокращениях**](https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL03/70091445.html) говорится в "Справочнике издателя и автора" (А. Э. Мильчин, Л. К. Чельцова):

> [**4.3.3**] Ставится дефис: <...>
> 2) когда сокращается сложное слово, части которого в полной форме пишутся через дефис; напр.: *инж.-мех. — инженер-механик*...
> <...>
> [**4.5.3**] 6. В сложных прилагательных, пишущихся через дефис, каждая составная часть сокращается так же, как отдельные прилагательные. Напр.: *профессионально-технический — проф.-техн.*

Эта информация к тому, что дефис (**в-** и **во-**) при сокращении остается.

Слова *первых, вторых, третьих, десятых, сотых, тысяча-сто-тридцать-восьмых* (без "одна") сокращаются по правилам для числительных — тоже с дефисом.

Получаем: **во-1-х, во-2-х, в-3-х, в-10-х, в-100-х, в-1138-х.**

•• Я бы написала таким образом:

*В-тысяча-сто-тридцать-восьмых, я хочу сказать, что это всё.

В-1138-х, я хочу сказать, что это всё.

Во-2-х, я устал.*

••• Имеются и примеры:

*Товар есть, **во-1-х,** вещь, удовлетворяющая какой-либо потребности человека; **во-2-х,** вещь, обмениваемая на другую вещь* (В. И. Ленин. Карл Маркс).
***В-сто-первых,** я люблю людей, школьников* (Захар Дей).

Comment: Есть ли примеры сложных прилагательных не из двух, а много более частей, пишущихся через дефис?

Comment: Плюсую ответ-т.

Comment: Потратила на оформление много времени. Мне вопрос показался очень интересным, нестандартным — *конкретных* правил-то нет. А плюсики — это хорошо, здорово. Значит, не зря. Спасиб-бо!